# Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I've error

> [js] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject
>   to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option
>   to remove this warning.

when I try to use @track in lightning web component

Here is the code

```
import { LightningElement , track } from 'lwc';

export default class Helloworld extends LightningElement {
    @track greeting = 'World';

    changeHandler(event) {
        this.greeting = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

[image]

I don't have a Jsonconfig file and tried to add manually but also didn't work
[image]

Comment: can you post relevant code? I was able to use @track without any issues

Comment: import { LightningElement , track } from 'lwc';

export default class Helloworld extends LightningElement {
    @track greeting = 'World';
    
    changeHandler(event) {
        this.greeting = event.target.value;
    }
}

Comment: can you edit the original question and put your code snippet there? its very hard to read from comments.

Comment: Just tried your code, it worked charm, can you post screenshot of the error and some additional info if possible? and are you using VSCode and is your plugin on latest version?

Comment: kindly check it

Comment: Do you have any other VSCode plugins? I've had my typescript linting plugin play up in this way with some of my LWC files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to enable that in compiler options.

Open `jsconfig.json` file and set that attribute `experimentalDecorators` inside `compilerOptions` as true. It will fix your issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have a jsonconfig file so i tried to put it manual and add the code in your screenshot but also it didn't work .I've edited the question

Comment: In VSCode, Go to File => Preferences => Settings (or Control+comma) and it will open the User Settings file. Add "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true to the file and it should fix it. It did for me.

Comment: @MayarAhmed - if this answer fixed your problem, please check it as `accepted`

Answer (score 11):

In your Visual Code Studio go to

File => Preferences => Settings

In the "Search Settings" Type "Experimental Decorators" and Enable its checkbox.

Comment: This is the only way I could get the error to go away even when  "experimentalDecorators":true thing set correctly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

{
    "compilerOptions" :{
        "experimentalDecorators":true,
        "baseUrl":".",
        "paths":{}
    }
}

Comment: Can you add further informations in order to explain what your code done ?!